# Set custom template path to render instead of standard one

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

Is it possible in `ZendFramework` to set custom template when I call some action ?
For example I call `/category/show/id/123` and `View` is rendering `/category/show.html` file.

I want to be able to render anonther template - `/category/showOther.html`.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure. In your ControllerAction do this:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('showOther');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1><?php echo sprintf($this->translate('Welcome to %sZend Framework 2%s'), '<span class="zf-green">', '</span>') ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo sprintf($this->translate('Congratulations! You have successfully installed the %sZF2 Skeleton Application%s. You are currently running Zend Framework version %s. This skeleton can serve as a simple starting point for you to begin building your application on ZF2.'), '<a href="https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication" target="_blank">', '</a>', \Zend\Version\Version::VERSION) ?></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="https://github.com/zendframework/zf2" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->translate('Fork Zend Framework 2 on GitHub') ?> &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo $this->translate('Follow Development') ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p><?php echo sprintf($this->translate('Zend Framework 2 is under active development. If you are interested in following the development of ZF2, there is a special ZF2 portal on the official Zend Framework website which provides links to the ZF2 %swiki%s, %sdev blog%s, %sissue tracker%s, and much more. This is a great resource for staying up to date with the latest developments!'), '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Home">', '</a>', '<a href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog">', '</a>', '<a href="https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues">', '</a>') ?></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="http://framework.zend.com/zf2" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->translate('ZF2 Development Portal') ?> &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
```